# Using a Regex to alter QR Code text in textbox C# Barcode Scanner

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a Windows Forms stock locator application in C#.

What I want to achieve is when the user clicks "Locate Stock" the application will run the regex on the string scanned by the barcode scanner and then run the sql query.

Example of the QR Code - PO00323,**ME-CAL-TOL-150**,18/01/2016 10:03:10,12389

We require the part on bold, the regex, should remove all other text leaving this which the Sql query will then use.

I've a feeling the regex part should go in the locateStock_Click button but I can't get it to tidy up the scanned string. I've looked at several tutorials on YouTube but they all do this for a C# Console Application and I can't piece it together for a Web Form App.

```
string input = textBox1.Text;
            string pattern = @"^[A-z]{2}[0-9]{5},|,|[0-9]{4}|\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{0}|\s..|[,.*?:/]\d.{1,}";
            string replacement = "";
            string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Full Code;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cleattextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void locateStock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = textBox1.Text;
        string pattern = @"^[A-z]{2}[0-9]{5},|,|[0-9]{4}|\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{0}|\s..|[,.*?:/]\d.{1,}";
        string replacement = "";
        string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);

        this.iCITEMOTableAdapter.FillBy(this.sTGCOMDataSet.ICITEMO, textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void iCITEMOBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string textboxValue = textBox1.Text;
        string sql = "SELECT ITEMNO, VALUE " +
           "FROM dbo.ICITEMO " +
           "WHERE OPTFIELD LIKE '%LOCATION1%' '" + textboxValue + "' and ITEMNO = @ITEMNO";
    }
```

Comment: Are the strings consistent? Might be simpler to split on commas.

Comment: There are slight variations, however, the regex will cover those. The regex will work, what I can't get the code to do is actually replace the input string.

Comment: So, in `locateStock_Click` insert `textBox1.Text = result;` before the last line?

Comment: I've actually managed to get it to work to a degree. It now will run the regex pattern on the scanned QR Code but it seems to remove everything but the last two characters. Code is:  `private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string input = textBox1.Text;
            textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(input, @"^[A-z]{2}[0-9]{5},|[0-9]{4}|\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{0}|\s..|[,.*?:/]\d.{1,}", "");
        }`

Answer (score 0):

This pattern `(\w+-)+[^,]+` will extract only what was bolded.

```
var txt = "PO00323,ME-CAL-TOL-150,18/01/2016 10:03:10,12389";
var pattern = @"(\w+-)+[^,]+";
Console.WriteLine( Regex.Match(txt, pattern).Value ); // ME-CAL-TOL-150
```